# Cant start angular project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-cli, path-variables

I was having some problems with an angular project so i reinstalled nodejs and angular cli however now when i try to run
`ng serve`
i get this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4xLV.png)

now ive done the typical google searching for this problem and it led me to stackoverflow with making sure the nodejs is in the enviroment variables path and it was already there:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJv3y.png)

also i checked the path to verify it and here is the folder:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kKWn.png)

i tried to be as thorough as possible before coming here to ask this question. i dont know how to fix this when the path is correct. please help!!

Comment: can you check node version node -v. let me know which version you're using.

Comment: @Dakopatel ok sir youve helped me more than you know. for some reason i went to check the node -v and it said node wasnt recognized. so i reinstalled nodejs. then found some other errors but i was able to fix everything and now ng serve works. if i hadnt have checked the node -v i never would have found all the other errors. thank you so much!!!

Comment: Cool ! Don't call me sir I am just 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try checking your node version to see if you have node properly
  installed.
- Maybe your CMD was opened before the path was set, try
  opening a new CMD window and execute the same command again.